# Python Wrong Input when working with Lists

Tags: python, list

I am working with this problem (https://open.kattis.com/problems/whowantstoliveforever). As the problem states, my program has to determine if the universe lives or dies based on the input 0s and 1s.

```
to determine the next value of the i-th bit, look at the current value of the bits at positions i−1 and i+1 (if they exist; otherwise assume them to be 0). If you see exactly one 1, then the next value of the i-th bit is 1, otherwise it is 0. All the bits change at once, so the new values in the next state depend only on the values in the previous state. We consider the universe dead if it contains only zeros.
```

My current solution works on the example input file, however it fails when submitting it to Kattis. (Wrong Answer)

Below is my code.

```
import sys


def get_bit(bits, i):
    if 0 <= i < len(bits):
        return int(bits[i])
    else:
        return 0


def get_new_state(old_state):
    new_state = []
    for index in range(len(old_state)):
        if (get_bit(old_state, index-1) == 0 and get_bit(old_state, index+1) == 0) or (get_bit(old_state, index-1) == 1 and get_bit(old_state, index+1) == 1):
            new_state.append(0)
        elif(get_bit(old_state, index-1) == 0 and get_bit(old_state, index+1) == 1) or (get_bit(old_state, index-1) == 1 and get_bit(old_state, index+1) == 0):
            new_state.append(1)
    return new_state


def is_dead(state):
    if len(set(state)) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def foresee_fate(state):
    seen = []
    while True:
        if is_dead(state):
            return False
        if state in seen:
            return True
        seen.append(state)
        state = get_new_state(state)


def print_result(boolean):
    print("LIVES" if boolean else "DIES")


num_cases = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
for i in range(num_cases):
    cur_state = []
    case = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    for char in case:
        cur_state.append(char)
    print_result(foresee_fate(cur_state))
```

Please let me know what I can do to improve this program.

Comment: Does it fail on Kattis because it times out (algorithm efficiency issue) or gives incorrect outputs?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog my programs gives incorrect outputs

Comment: It looks like you're only checking the length of the set of values...what if the bits are all `1`? `is_dead` would still return True, but the `bitverse` wouldn't be dead (all zeros)

Comment: Can you be specific with the errors? I think code works fine but its printing as soon as the input for a case is given, but program should wait till all the inputs are given and then print the output. Sample input is satisfied

Comment: @ritheesh Kattis.com literally says "Wrong answer" and doesn't give me anything else so I am not sure what the specific problem is.

Comment: @G.Anderson I see. Thanks, I will try it out

Comment: @KimRuhol I execued it code was fine, try appending result to a list in for loop and print the list outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I have added the following to my code and IT works now. However, I ran into a new problem. now I'm getting `"Time Limit Exceeded" > 3.00 s`.

```
def is_dead(state):
    if set(state).pop() == 1:
        return False
    elif len(set(state)) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Please let me know if there is any suggestion on getting around this problem

Comment: Now that your code works but you want to improve it, you might try opening a new question on the [codereview.se] stack site. One optimization I can see with this snippet: You're constructing your set twice, once in each `if` condition. Why not a `sum` instead of a constructing a set (a moderately "expensive" operation) then doing a `len` check? After all, `sum([0,0,0,0,0...0])` == `0`